# How to turn a month string into a month int in Google Spreadhseets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to take the name of a month, such as `October` and turn that into the corresponding number for that month `10`. Past making a long formula that checks for each month by string, and without using apps script to create a custom function (not reliable enough).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cell A1 contains the name of the month, then the command

```
=month(datevalue(A1&" 1"))
```

returns the number of the month. It appends a day to the month (1), so that [`datevalue`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en) can parse the date; then [`month`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en) returns the month number.

Comment: Nice! Does this work in locales that format dates differently?

Comment: Datevalue takes locale and language into account when parsing strings. But I think that October 1 is unambiguous... assuming English language, which is given in the problem. To have completely self contained solution, I would use a helper table and Vlookup function.