# How to turn a list of months string into a list of month numbers?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with month headers at the top:

```
January | February | March | ...
```

Is there a way with one formula that I can get a list of month numbers?

```
January | February | March | ...
--------+----------+-------+----
      1 |        2 |     3 | ...
```

I saw [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85856/111648) about turning a month string into a month number with `=MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))` but when I tried to do `=ARRAYVALUE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1:1 & " 1")))` it didn't work. In fact `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1:1 & " 1"))` gives the same result as `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `arrayvalue` command; there is `arrayformula`.

Yes, `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1:1 & " 1"))` gives the same result as `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))` because without `arrayformula`, it expects one value as an argument. Given more, it only takes the first one.

The correct formula (tested in my spreadsheet) is

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1:1 & " 1")))
```

Comment: Oh whoops. I meant ARRAYFORMULA. I just tried it in a new sheet and it worked, but it's not working in a different sheet I have. There must be some sort of collision happening.

Comment: Sometimes the data present in the sheet prevent the output of arrayformula from expanding. Also, consider whether you really need `A1:1` - presumably there are just 12 months, so `A1: L1` would be enough.